# React Native Linking Deep Link Doesn't Open on First Load

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I'm trying to enable deeplink in my React Native project, and have it working for all use-cases where the deeplink opens the app from the background, not from the first load. I believe the issue is that my path that I am deep-linking, is not available until after the "loading screen" has gone away.

For example I have this setup as my `RootStack.Navigator`

```
 <RootStack.Navigator
      detachInactiveScreens={false}
      headerMode="none"
      initialRouteName={"AppTabsScreen"}
      screenOptions={{ animationEnabled: false }}
      mode="modal"
    >
      {isLoading ? (
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="LoadingScreen"
          component={LoadingScreen}
          options={{ animationEnabled: true }}
        />
      ) : user ? (
        <RootStack.Screen name="AppTabsScreen" component={AppTabsScreen} />
      ) : (
        <RootStack.Screen name="AuthStackScreen" component={AuthStackScreen} />
      )}
...
```

And my linking config as:

```
const deepLinksConf = {
  screens: {
    AppTabsScreen: {
      screens: {
        initialRouteName: "Activity",
        Activity: {
          screens: {
            Activity: "activity",
            Details: "workout/:userId/:id",
          },
        },
        Goals: {
          screens: {
            Goals: "goal",
            GoalDetail: "goal/:id",
          },
        },
        Settings: "settings",
        Profile: "profile",
      },
    },
  }
};
```

In my `getInitialURL()` function, I get the URL correctly, but I believe the path is already on the `LoadingScreen`, and not the `AppTabsScreen`, which causes it not to fire. Is there anyway around this situation? How can I delay the deeplink to wait until the `AppTabScreen` is present to process the link? This works fine when the app is the fore or background, but never at first start.

```
....
async getInitialURL() {

        console.log("fired");
        // Check if app was opened from a deep link
        const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();

        console.log("deeplinking");
        console.log(url);

        if (url != null) {
          console.log("just returning");
          return url;
        }

        // Check if there is an initial firebase notification
        const message = await messaging().getInitialNotification();

        // Get deep link from data
        // if this is undefined, the app will open the default/home page
        return messsage.data?.link;
  },
```

I am using `react-navigation`, and my main navigation controller is as follows:

```
<NavigationContainer
      linking={linking}
      theme={scheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => {
        if (navigationRef.current) {
          routeNameRef.current = navigationRef?.current.getCurrentRoute().name;
        }
      }}
      onStateChange={async () => {
        const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
        const currentRouteName = navigationRef?.current.getCurrentRoute().name;

        if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
          await analytics().logScreenView({
            screen_name: currentRouteName,
            screen_class: currentRouteName,
          });
        }

        // Save the current route name for later comparision
        routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
      }}
    >
      <FlashMessage position="top" />
      <RootStackScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>
```